Why did Star-Lord say "Past Gamora" instead of "New Gamora" if she changed?
At Orgocorp, after acquiring the 89P13 patent by threatening Ura,
Nebula, Star-Lord, and Gamora are clearly surrounded by Orgosentries:

Gamora: Lower your weapons! Let's kill that one that looks like  a
carrot to show we mean business.
Star-Lord: God! Past Gamora's just mean!

Why did Star-Lord say "Past Gamora" instead of "New Gamora" if she changed?

He's totally not saying what people usually say when an alternate-universe version of their dead lover behaves aggressively in an armed confrontation with aliens who occasionally look like earth vegetables!

The Gamora that exists here is the one that was brought by a past Thanos, thereby being the Gamora who existed years prior to the current time. Thus, Peter refers to her as "past Gamora" rather than the one who had evolved over the years that he had known her.

Specifically as I recall she's from the universe that was about to do Guardians of the Galaxy 1 before different events happened.
